# How to implement wso2 on server?

Tags: wso2

I would like to implement WSO2 as Identity and Access Management on a server to control some small business users. It's a project for the vocational school. It would be possible for free? I'm sorry but I'm a bit lost with all this.

Thank you very much in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WSO2 as Identity and Access Management on a server to control some small business users

Indeed WSO2 Identity Server (wso2is) is intended for that. The applications on the server will have to use an authorization protocol (SAML, OAuth, ..) to enforce the user access.

Without any more specific questions / information about your case you probably won't get any more specific answer.

> It would be possible for free?

It depends.

Indeed, WSO2 products are open source, so you can use them freely and update them as you wish.

On the other hand some institutions require to have supported all deployed products, so you should check what rules apply to your case.

As well you may consider subscription to help you stay current with patches and updates, however it depends on your policies and budget.